# Find min and max of non-zero values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, max, series, min

I try to get the min and max value (as a float) of a column without the zero values.

I tried:

```
minValue = df[df['col1']>0.1].min()
maxValue = df['col2'].max()
```

type minValue --> pandas.core.series.Series
type maxValue --> float

Comment: "without the non-zero values" means you only want to look at the zeros. Which sounds wrong.

Comment: But the answer would be much simpler then: 0. ;-)

Comment: so, what failed? Can you provide a reproducible input/output example?

Comment: did you display/print minValue? I think it would help you see what the operation currently does

Comment: I think you missed to select the column where to calculate the min, try : `minValue = df[df['col1']>0.1]['col1'].min()`

Comment: Ok , i meant without zero values.  The solution was provided by Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```py
minValue = df.col1[df.col1!=0].min()
maxValue = df.col1[df.col2!=0].max()
```

but you need to adapt to the columns you want to look for non-zero values and from which you want the min/max values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
minValue = df.loc[df['col1']>0.1, 'col1'].min()
```